# Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.util.ImmutableCollections$Set12 to java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-boot-3

After migration from spring-data-jpa 2.7.1 to 3.1.2 (SpringBoot 3.1.2 migration) in method:

```java
@Query("""
    SELECT o
    FROM Storage o
    WHERE o.status = 'SUCCESS'
    AND (
        (:referenceNumbers) IS NULL
        OR o.referenceNumber IN (:referenceNumbers)
    )
    ...
""")
Page<Storage> findObject(ObjectFilter filter, Set<String> referenceNumbers, Iterable<Long> systemIds, Pageable pageable);
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Accessors(chain = true)
class Storage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String referenceNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
}
```

I'm getting:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.util.**ImmutableCollections$Set12 to java.lang.String :** `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType` (java.lang.String)

Seems like `IN` method is not able to handle Collection anymore

I was trying to find documentation for JPQL `IN` method but could not find anything relevant.

For Spring Data JPA 2.7.1, this method was working perfectly fine.

I tried to find documentation for the `IN` method for Spring Data JPA 3.1.2, because I have many similar methods in project and my app might be working with many databases (PostgreSQL, Oracle).

Comment: Can you show your `Object`? I assume you are not referring to `java.lang.Object` but something else you just called `Object` in your question for demonstration. Maybe try removing the brackets around `:referenceNumbers`.

Comment: It doesn't compile without    ':'

Comment: I am not talking about the colon but the parenthesis around it.

Comment: Does it work if you don't have the `IS NULL` check? Does that effect the exception?

Comment: IN (:referenceNumbers) - > IN :referenceNumbers doesn't make any difference but 
without  IS NULL it's working :)

Comment: Does the exception also occur with the `IS NULL` but without the `IN`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `(:referenceNumbers) IS NULL` is the problem.
You can split the query method in two methods, one with custom logic for handling that:

```java
@Query("SELECT o FROM Storage o WHERE o.status = 'SUCCESS' " +
" AND (:ignoreReferenceNumbers OR o.referenceNumber IN (:referenceNumbers)) " +"...")
Page<Storage> findObjectInternal(ObjectFilter filter, Set<String> referenceNumbers, boolean ignoreReferenceNumbers, Iterable<Long> systemIdsPageable pageable);

default Page<Storage> findObject(ObjectFilter filter, Set<String> referenceNumbers, Iterable<Long> systemIds,Pageable pageable){
    if(referenceNumbers==null){
        return findObjectInternal(filter, Collections.emptyList(), true, systemIds, pageable);
    }
    return findObjectInternal(filter, referenceNumbers, false, systemIds, pageable);
}
```

or use two (overloaded) `default` methods:

```java
@Query("SELECT o FROM Storage o WHERE o.status = 'SUCCESS' " +
" AND (:ignoreReferenceNumbers OR o.referenceNumber IN (:referenceNumbers)) " +"...")
Page<Storage> findObjectInternal(ObjectFilter filter, Set<String> referenceNumbers, boolean ignoreReferenceNumbers, Iterable<Long> systemIdsPageable pageable);

default Page<Storage> findObject(ObjectFilter filter, Set<String> referenceNumbers, Iterable<Long> systemIds,Pageable pageable){
    return findObjectInternal(filter, referenceNumbers, false, systemIds, pageable);
}

default Page<Storage> findObject(ObjectFilter filter, Iterable<Long> systemIds,Pageable pageable){
    return findObjectInternal(filter, Collections.emptyList(), true, systemIds, pageable);
}
```

and always call the corresponding default method instead of using a `null` argument.
As [mentioned by the OP in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857226/unknown-wrap-conversion-requested-java-util-immutablecollectionsset12-to-java/76857629?noredirect=1#comment135495943_76857629), it is also possible like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT o FROM Storage o WHERE o.status = 'SUCCESS' " +
" AND (coalesce(:#{#referenceNumbers}, null) IS NULL OR o.referenceNumber IN (:referenceNumbers)) " +"...")
Page<Storage> findObject(ObjectFilter filter, Set<String> referenceNumbers, Iterable<Long> systemIds,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: This solution will work, but in some queries in a code I have 3 lines like this eg: 

(:referenceNumbers1) IS NULL
OR o.referenceNumber1 IN (:referenceNumbers1)  AND
 (:referenceNumbers2) IS NULL
        OR o.referenceNumber2 IN (:referenceNumbers2) AND
(:referenceNumbers3) IS NULL
        OR o.referenceNumber3 IN (:referenceNumbers3),

if solution won't work well here 

 but at least I know that is null is causing this problem

Comment: `" AND (coalesce(:#{#referenceNumbers}, null) IS NULL OR o.referenceNumber IN (:referenceNumbers) )" `

this approach solved my problem !!!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too, but I did an in-depth check and this error triggers because when for example `:listName` is `null`, Spring JPA `@Query` detects this and automatically converts that parameter into `String`.

To prevent that happening i have used this approach like example below using `Coalesce`:

```
select u from product u where  (Coalesce(:listProductName) is null or u.productName in :listProductName)
```

Hopefully, this approach can helpful.